# Batch Make 100MB Archive max with all files contained into a folder (Recursive)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory, 7zip

I am looking to create a program that would zip (using 7zip) all files contained into the folder (Recursivly) into an archive until the archive hits 100MB. Whenever it does, it would join in the .csv file associated with the file, delete it, create a new one with the next number and also create a new archive. It should do this until all files are archived into an archive (number doesn't matter as long as all the files added into an archive)

My example is not considering files inside sub-folders yet. (yeah, gotta start somewhere)

The example does something a little counter-logical, it does remove the last added file from the archive once it sees it's bigger than 100MB. Problem is, i don't think batch can evaluate the output of the archive before creating it, therefore it's a little workaround. That way it manages to find the size of the archive and afterwards determine if it's ok to go or if were done with this one.

I'm doing this because we need zip files being maxed out 100MB. It doesn't matter if i get 10 or 20 .zip files, it only matters that none bust 100MB. After that we'll use the output archives and upload them to archive it all.

As you can see it also ECHO Name,Type,File,Event into the newer file because the headers are required into the .csv file. It is required to put a .csv file into every archive, and this is why once it spots the 100MB cap it deletes the last added file, then put in the .csv and afterwards deletes it.

I have already taken care of unique file size, none of them are going to be bigger than 40MB, and only those lesser than 40MB are considered.

Anyway this is what i have so far but it doesn't want to work, for some reason it closes ASAP after i doubleclick my .bat

```
SET /a modif=1
SET "file=importationinfo"
SET "reqext=.csv"
ECHO Name,Type,File,Event> %file%%modif%%reqext%
FOR %%a IN (*.*) DO (
IF NOT %%~zi GTR 40999999 (
    IF /i NOT "%%~nxa"=="%~nx0" (
        IF /i NOT "%%~nxa"=="%file%%modif%%reqext%" (
            FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ("%%~dpa\.") DO (
                >>"%file%%modif%%reqext%" ECHO "%%~nxa","4","\%%~nxa","%ID%"
                "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip Import%modif%.zip "%%~nxa"
                FOR /F %%i IN ("Import%modif%.zip") DO SET "size=%%~zi"
                    ECHO %size%
                    IF %size% GTR 104857599 (
                    ECHO Bigger than 104857599 
                            REM This Echo is only for debugging
                    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" d -tzip Import%modif%.zip "%%~nxa"
                    PAUSE
                    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip Import%modif%.zip "%file%%modif%%reqext%"
                    DEL %file%%modif%%reqext%
                    SET /a modif+=1
                    ECHO Name,Type,File,Event> %file%%modif%%reqext%
                ) ELSE (
                    ECHO NOT 100MB YET
                    >>"%file%%modif%%reqext%" ECHO "%%~nxa","4","\%%~nxa","%ID%" )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

That is all. I really hope you guys can help me out on this.
Thanks.
J-P.

EDIT : I know it is possible to ask for maximum file size to 7z and zip them alltogether, and it'll automatically create multiple archives with .001 .002 ... filenames afterwards. But in this specific case this option is not OK, as the archives will not be used to recreate these files but to archive them (upload using .zip format). Therefore if any files is split into two different archive, this will cause problems. This is also why i want to join in a new .csv in every archive.

Comment: If you use `Winrar` you can set the file size in the command line.

Comment: I currently cannot used Winrar for this specific case. And i can also specify max size with 7z, but it might slice a file in half. I don't want that.

Comment: You can use `7za a -v100m "archive" "filemask"`! Otherwise good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might test this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "archive=test\archive"
SET "startfolder=%userprofile%"
SET /a maxsize=104857600

for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a-d "%startfolder%" ^| findstr /n $') DO (
    IF %%~za gtr %maxsize% (ECHO "%%a" too large (%%~za Bytes^) &GOTO :EOF)
    SET "$%%a=%%~fb"
    SET "filecount=%%a"
)
SET /a ptr=1
SET /a anr=1
:loop
CALL SET "file=%%$%ptr%%%"
ECHO adding "%file%" TO %archive%-%anr%.7z
START /b /w "7zip" "7za" a "%archive%-%anr%" "%file%" >NUL||(ECHO Error!&GOTO :EOF)
FOR  %%a IN ("%archive%-%anr%.7z") DO SET "asize=%%~za"
IF %asize% gtr %maxsize% (
    ECHO deleting "%file%" FROM %archive%-%anr%.7z
    START /b /w "7zip" "7za" d "%archive%-%anr%" "%file%" >NUL||(ECHO Error!&GOTO :EOF)
    SET /a anr+=1
) ELSE (
    SET /a ptr+=1
)
IF %ptr% leq %filecount% GOTO :loop
ECHO %filecount% file(s) added IN %anr% archive(s).
```

Note #1: the script doesn't work with `=` in file or path names
Note #2: the script will terminate, if it finds a file with a size greater than the archive size
Note #3: archive names will be created from `archive-1.7z`, `archive-2.7z`...
Note #4: because testing compression takes much time, I havn't tested very much
Note #5: because of your special needs the script works very slowly
<sub>*[Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).*</sub>

Comment: Endoro, First of all, thanks for the quick response. I will be testing this in the next moments and will tell you how it feels. Looking at it, it looks pretty neat. No worry about the speed; any batch program is faster than my users. They are smart but slow with computers :p

Comment: Back after multiple testing; first block "Crashing if find file bigger than 100MB" is not working, but i don't care since i deleted it all. Still, everything works after multiple changes. I'll show you once i'm done just so next users will have an answer.